# Migrating 300GB database to Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, migration, azure-sql-database

We are having a devil of a time trying to migrate our current on-premises SQL Server to an Azure SQL Database. It is large but not that large (about 300 GB). We've tried the "Publish to Azure" option from SQL Server and get errors and exceptions (out of memory exceptions). The Data Migration Assistant seems to start working OK, but it fails after 12 hours or so having completed only about 15% of the migration. We can't be down for 12 hours, let alone the time it would seem to take in order to move the complete 300 GB database.

What are some strategies and best practices that we could try for the data migration that would minimize downtime?

Comment: Locations? I think there was an option to send a hard disc at some point and Fedex ca nbe VERY fast if you pay (acutally they put people into jets if you pay).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Azure Data Migration Service located [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/database-migration/)? You can try the service for free from now until August 31, 2018. For more information, please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/dms-overview).

Answer (score 0):

To migrate 300GB SQL Server database to Azure you ca use any of these three techniques like:

1. SSMS **Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database**
2. **Export Data-Tier Application Process**
3. Third party tools like **SQL to Azure Migrator by SysTools**